# First letter browser conflict

Tags: css, cross-browser

I did a styling for my webpage paragraph, so it would have a nice paragraph first letter, it works fine on firefox:

[image: first letter]

and then I tried chrome:

[image: first letter 2]

Here's the code:

```
.about p{
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: timesnewroman;
    margin: 20px 80px 90px 80px;
}

.about p:first-letter{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: schmuckinitialen;
    font-size: 100px;
    float: left;
    height: 100px;
    /*padding-top: 50px;*/
}
```

I also tried giving it padding, and some other options, but it didn't help. Does someone know how to make this cross-browser?

**EDIT**
The case is solved. To clear things up for anyone who has questions, yes, this is a 100% web font generated in [fontsquirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator), and I am using official css reset.

Comment: I wonder, would embedding it as a web font have any difference in terms of consistency? (For better or worse)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try line-height attribute on the pseudo selector,

http://jsfiddle.net/59ZHU/2/

```
.about p:first-letter{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: schmuckinitialen;
    font-size: 100px;
    float: left;
    height: 100px; 
    line-height:87px; //Add this line
}
```

Comment: It works. Thank you so much, i thought i'll have too use scripting to determine the browser and add the padding-top...